# Understanding join() method in java () without mentioning calling thread

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code gives an output of 9; But my question is which thread will call join() method. main thread calls join method than what does it mean? all the other threads should wait till main method completes? Then the output shouldn't be 9?

```
public class Starter extends Thread {
    private int x = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Starter().makeItSo();
    }

    public Starter(){
        x = 5;
        start();
    }

    public void makeItSo() throws Exception {
        join();
        x = x - 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public void run() { x *= 2; }

}
```

Comment: This question was asked in scjp/ocjp exam and basic join method usage is easy to understand help me with this

Comment: `t.join()` returns when thread `t` has completed.  What else do you need to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Starter extends Thread {
  private int x = 2;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Start of main "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    new Starter().makeItSo();
    System.out.println("End of main "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }

  public Starter(){
    x = 5;
    System.out.println("Before starting thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    start();
    System.out.println("After starting thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }

  public void makeItSo() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Before join " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    join();
    System.out.println("After join " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    x = x - 1;
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }

  public void run() {
    System.out.println("Inside running thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName() +"with value of x:" +x);
    x *= 2;
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Start of main main
Before starting thread main
After starting thread main
Before join main
Inside running thread Thread-0with value of x:5
After join main
9
main
End of main main
```

Go through the code and it is pretty much self explanatory. The main thread is the one which waits at join for thread-0 spawned at the constructor to get completed. The main thread doesnt end untill the `makeItSo()` function call ends.

Comment: How come the main thread is inside the makeItSo()? Shouldn't the new Thread i.e. Thread-0, be the thread in which makeItSo() is executed (because .makeItSo() is called on the new Starter())?

Comment: Why would a new thread run inside makeItSo() ? the part inside makeItSo is just sequential not parallel... The main thread is executing sequentially till it reaches join() statement inside makeItSo().. there it waits for the new Thread-0 that executes run() method to complete..  The part inside run() is running in parallel by the new thread...

Answer (score 1):

That `join()` in `makeItSo()` is indeed confusing. Your code is equivalent (ignoring exceptions) to this, with the `join()` removed from `makeItSo()`, and removing `start()` from the `Starter` constructor:

```
Starter other_thread = new Starter();
other_thread.start(); // run gets executed in other_thread
other_thread.join();  // waits for other_thread to finish running
other_thread.makeItSo();
```

As in your code, it is the main thread that calls `join` on the secondary thread. That causes the main thread to wait for the end of `run()` before computing `x-1` and printing it out.

So the secondary thread will have computed `x*2 -> 10`, and the main thread computes `x - 1 -> 9` after that thanks to the `join()`.

Answer (score 0):

The main thread calls the  join method, so it will wait for the thread spawned by Starter to stop.  When you invode new Starter() it starts a thread, that finishes quickly.  It's possible make is so will wait a bit until starter finishes.  For a better test put a sleep in run and track the elapsed time. You will see that it wait for Starter to end.